# How to register sequential point clouds gathered from a walk down a hallway

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

For our university project we captured a .oni video while walking down a hallway. We then converted each frame of the .oni video to a .pcd file. What do you think the best way would be to stitch these cloud files together to recreate a single point cloud representing the entire captured hallway. I'm not sure if iterative closest point or feature based registration would fit this better. Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the PCL registration API. For example take a look at the ["How to incrementally register pairs of clouds" tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pairwise_incremental_registration.php#pairwise-incremental-registration). That uses ICP.

Also take a look at the other [registration related tutorials](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/#registration-tutorial).